# Minecraft Optifine - where is the zoom class?

Tags: minecraft-modding

I'm working on a mod where I want to have a zoom feature like Optifine. To start out, I want to try messing around with the zoom in the actual Optifine mod. There are a lot of .class files, and I don't want to decompile all of them one by one, so if anyone knows which one(s) have the zoom that would be super helpful.

Comment: Optifine just lowers the FOV to achieve that effect. Do you really need to decompile the mod to test this?

Comment: Oh ok never mind I thought it was more complex than that. Thanks.